# How do I make the icons smaller in Stacks grid view for Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, icons, grid, stacks

Since I installed Snow Leopard, I'm stuck with *huge* icons in my stacks/folder views in my dock. It use to adjust the layout and size of the window so that as many icons as possible fit on the screen, but now it shows huge icons and a scrollbar instead. I'd like the old behavior back so I don't have to scroll anymore.

Does anyone know where the setting for this is? Maybe hidden in some .plist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible in Lion. Just press ⌘- or ⌘+ in the grid.

Comment: Very glad to have found this tip - makes the grid view usable! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look to be possible, going by this current discussion at the Apple forum: [Topic : Stacks have huge icons! (in grid view)](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2133451&tstart=0&start=0).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do so, but you can make them smaller by adding more items or using the fan or list views...
Sorry I'm not more help!

Comment: Hmmm, adding more items only adds an annoying scrollbar on my Mac. Do the icons on your Mac scale to fit in a window without a scrollbar? (And are you on 10.6?)

Answer (score 0):

The Correct way of making your icons smaller using Mac OS X Lion is by first opening the folder to where you can view all the icons, now as what was stated earlier you will have you most pointer inside the folder with the icons, First push and hold COMMAND while pushing either - or + and there you go your icon will change!

Answer (score 0):

The trick: In Terminal, tested in Lion and Snow Leopard:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock use-new-list-stack -boolean YES
killall Dock
```

Then you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> while a Dock based list/grid is open.

Comment: On Lion, ⌘+ and ⌘- work by default when stacks are viewed as a grid. `use-new-list-stack` has to be enabled only when they're viewed as a list.